# How to extract persons on a wikipedia list using dbpedia/sparql

Tags: sparql, wikipedia, dbpedia

I'm trying to extract all persons that won a (Gold) medal at the Olympics and ideally their birth location using the dbpedia SPARQL query. Basically it's this list I'm aiming at: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_olympischen_Medaillengewinner_aus_Spanien

I guess it must somehow work with this piece of code:

`yago-res:wikicategory_Olympic_bronze_medalists_for_Spain`

This doesn't work:

```
SELECT ?res    
WHERE { 
   ?res yago-res:wikicategory_Olympic_bronze_medalists_for_Spain .
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: what is the class that you want the instances of ?

Comment: http://mappings.dbpedia.org/server/ontology/classes/#Olympics ?

Answer (score 1):

To get all the spanish persons that have won the gold medal in olympic

```
select ?person where 
{
    ?person a <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/OlympicGoldMedalistsForSpain>
}
```

If you look at what dbpedia has, there is no class:

```
http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/OlympicGoldMedalists
```

but there is

```
http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/OlympicGoldMedalistsForItaly
```

and

```
http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/OlympicGoldMedalistsForFrance
```

and

```
http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/OlympicGoldMedalistsForGermany
```

so a work around could be:

```
    select distinct ?person ?birthPlace where 
{
    ?goldForCountry rdfs:subClassOf yago:Medalist110305062 .
    ?person a ?goldForCountry .
    optional{
        ?person dbo:birthPlace ?birthPlace
    }
    filter (contains(str(?goldForCountry), "http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/OlympicGoldMedalistsFor"))
}
```

The `birthPlace` should be optional because there are 3994 persons that dbpedia doesn't have their birth place

Comment: Works fine. Thank you very much. Do you have an idea how to add the birth place into to final results?

Comment: thank you! Works fine, too. I meant birth place though, not date. But got it by replacing birthDate by birthPlace.

Comment: @ChrisEnroute my bad sorry, but yeah there is a birthPlace predicate as well